# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ consists precisely of the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ which satisfy $x^2 + ax + b=0$, $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I was reading Neurkich's "Algebraic Number Theory" and there was a proof in it that makes no sense.

> Proposition 1.5: $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ consists precisely of the elements of the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ which satisfy a monic polynomial equation, $x^2 + ax + b = 0$, with coefficients $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

While it is clear that all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ satisfy such an equation, the statement that every that satisfies such an equation is in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ doesn't seem to be true.

The proof started with suppose $\alpha = c+ id$ is a solution. Then it follows that $a = -2c$ and $b = c^2  + d^2$. It then states that if $a$ and $b$ are integers than so are $2c$ and $2d$, but I cannot figure out how you can conclude $2d$ is an integer.

Furthermore the monic polynomial equation $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$ has solutions $(1\pm i\sqrt{3})/2$ which does not appear to be a Gaussian integer at all.

Am I missing something? How is this supposed to work?

Comment: For the former question, use the fact that $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 \equiv 0\pmod{4}$ iff $\alpha, \beta \equiv 0\pmod{4}$. (Note that if $x\in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ has $x^2 + ax + b$ and $x\not\in \mathbb{Q}$, then the other root of that polynomial is just $\overline{x}$.) For the second part, $(1 \pm \sqrt{3})/2\not \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$. The question is more or less just asking you to prove that $\cal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(i)} = \mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: You know $a=-2c$ hence $c=-a/2$. Now let $d=p/q$ and use that $b=c^2+d^2$ is an integer. What can you say about $q$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Show that if $x\in\mathbb Q$ is a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$, then $x\in\mathbb Z$.
2. $(c+id)^2+a(c+id)+b=0$ leads to $c^2-d^2+ac+b=0$ and $2cd+ad=0$. The last equation writes $(2c+a)d=0$, and then
   (i) $d=0$; apply 1.
   (ii) $2c+a=0$; now the first equation becomes $(2d)^2+a^2-4b=0$, so $2d\in\mathbb Z$. Set $e=2d$. Then $e^2+a^2=4b$. If $e$ and/or $a$ are odd, then $e^2+a^2$ can't be a multiple of $4$ (why?), so both are even, and this shows that $c,d\in\mathbb Z$.